# iOS 12: How to add UIView to UIViewController programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I use old way to inject `UIView` to `UIViewController`, but after upgrade to iOS 12, it won't work and the error is:
`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Here is the code

```
class SlideOutMenu: UIViewController {
    var contentView:UIView!

    func setContentViewIn(view: UIView) {
        self.contentView = view
        self.view.addSubview(self.contentView)
    }
}
```

Then

```
class MainController: UIViewController {
    var slide = SlideOutMenu()
    var viewToAdd = ViewToAdd() // extends UIView
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slide.setContentViewIn(viewToAdd)
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, but if i declare like this, it works

```
class SlideOutMenu: UIViewController {
    var contentView:UIView!
    convenience init(childView: UIView) {
        self.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
        self.contentView = childView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.addSubview(self.contentView)
    }
}
```

And use

```
SlideOutMenu(childView: UIView())
```

It works.

But like this, it doesn't. That is weird

```
SlideOutMenu(childView: viewToAdd)
```

Comment: I don't think that the crash is related to the view. At its core you are just adding a subview.

Comment: ```self.contentView = view / view.addSubview(self.contentView)``` You are adding the view as subview to itself. That won't work ever. You might want to change the last line in ```self.view.addSubview(self.contentView)```.

Comment: @danypata i initialized the view by passing other view instance to it. check this code: https://github.com/chidori-app/CDRTranslucentSideBar/blob/master/CDRTranslucentSideBar/CDRTranslucentSideBar/CDRTranslucentSideBar.m#L513 it works fine until iOS12

Comment: It may have worked, but it shouldn't have done. Looks like now they've fixed it.

Comment: @TomSawyer You are missing the ```self.view```, the param name in your ```setContentViewIn``` overrides the ```view``` property of the controller.  Please change the last line of your setContentViewIn to ```self.view.addSubview(self.contentView)```

Comment: @danypata sorry, i missed it, i updated the question. It works, but only with `SlideOutMenu(childView: UIView())`, not with `SlideOutMenu(childView: viewToAdd)`

Answer (score -1):

This below code working in iOS 12 checked*
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var view1 : UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    view1 = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    view1.center = self.view.center
    view1.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(self.view1)
}
```

}
*

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample of how I build views programmatically:

```
class InformationController: UIViewController {

    let labelDescription: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.text = "Label Name"
        // this is important for auto layout to work
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        // add the view
        view.addSubview(labelDescription)

        // set the auto layout and enable the constraints
        labelDescription.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        labelDescription.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        labelDescription.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        labelDescription.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    }
}
```